# SELECT 1=1 not working

Tags: sql-server

My question is a bit more generic, but let's say I want to test some expression in SQL Server. I write `SELECT 1=1` or `SELECT 'a' > 'B'` and press F5, hoping to see the result, like I do when I type `SELECT 0, 1`.
But I get an error instead. Why is that? What should I use to evaluate those expressions on the fly?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't have a boolean data type.

You would need to use `SELECT CASE WHEN 1=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`

Comment: +1 No boolean data type ? I never realized that. I am so surprised, but it makes sense since I always used a bit for boolean data, and your answer already has 7 votes ...

Answer (score 16):

Simplest way is to `select 1 where <test expression here>`

Answer (score 2):

You could put your expression after `where` like this

```
select 'true' where 1=1
select 'true' where 1<>1
```

of you could put it in an IF statement

```
IF 1+1=2
BEGIN
   PRINT 'One and one makes two.'
END
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a case statement:

```
select case when 1=1 then 'true' else 'false' end
select case when 'a'>'B' then 'true' else 'false' end
```

or an IF...ELSE

```
if 1=1
    select 'true'
else
    select 'false'

if 'a' > 'B'
    select 'true'
else
    select 'false'
```

Comment: Why the downvote for a valid answer? In fact, the first half of my answer is the same as the current top-voted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to turn the output of the comparison to pseudo-boolean:

```
select isnull((select 'false' where not(1**0=1**)) ,'true')
```

or, to have an int as return:

```
select isnull((select 1 where 1<1) ,0)
```